# UGameplayStatics Emitter Attached but not completing

Tags: c++, animation, static, unreal-engine4, particles

I have created a particle effect and I am attaching it using `UGameplayStatics::SpawnEmitterAttached(Elecricity, gunMesh, TEXT("MuzzleFlashSocket"));`
but the particle effect isn't completing.

Electricity = UParticleSystem, gunMesh = USkeletalMeshComponent, TEXT("MuzzleFlashSocket") = Name of the socket.

I have tried setting both KillOnComplete and KillOnDeactivate but to no avail.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Check OutputLog : *LogScript: Warning: UGameplayStatics::SpawnEmitterAttached: NULL AttachComponent specified!*

```
theMesh = Cast<UStaticMeshComponent>(GetDefaultSubobjectByName(TEXT("Gun_SkeletalMesh")));
```

OR

```
theMesh = Cast<UStaticMeshComponent>(this->FindComponentByClass(UStaticMeshComponent::StaticClass()));
```

Otherwise

```
theMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Gun_SkeletalMesh"));
theMesh->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
```